# Select Item inside ListBox items

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listbox

I made a customizable calendar, in which I display a list of months.
When I move my mouse, I see the mouse goes over the `ListBox.Item`, but cannot make any selection when clicking.
**Edit : I am wrong, the 'ListBox.Item' gets selected, only if I click outside of its subitems (days).**
I would like to select only one day of my month.
I tried to set all `BackGround property` to `Transparent`, but it doesn't change behaviour.
How could I select not ListBox items, but items that are inside ListBox items?(the days)

Here is xaml I actually have :

```
<Window x:Class="VSTEEL.CustomizedCalendarMenu.CustomizedCalendar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:VSTEEL.CustomizedCalendarMenu.ViewModel"
        Title="CustomizedCalendar" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:VSTEEL.CustomizedCalendarMenu.ViewModel">

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LABEL.WEEK">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 2 0 2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Border 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="LBXI.DAY">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <Border.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWorkingDay}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWorkingDay}" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0000"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Border.Style>

                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Opacity="1" FontSize="12" Margin="2,2,0,0" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                                </Grid>
                                
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="monthTemplate">
                    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource LBXI.DAY}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <UniformGrid Columns="7">
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="MON" Background="#FFFFEAEA"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="TUE" Background="#FFE8F9FF"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="WED" Background="#FFE1F1C5"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="THU" Background="#FFFFD7D7"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="FRI" Background="#FFE9F9E4"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="SAT" Background="#FFF7F6E3"/>
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="SUN" Background="#FFC4DAE4"/>
                                        </UniformGrid>

                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="7"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="yearTemplate">
                    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListDays}" Style="{StaticResource monthTemplate}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="Preview" Click="nextMonth_Click" Margin="4" Padding="4"/>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="previousMonth_Click" Margin="4" Padding="4"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListMonths}">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListDays}" Style="{StaticResource monthTemplate}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You have not defined the visual element which corresponds to IsSelected property value in LBXI.DAY and thus cannot see whether it is actually selected or not.

Comment: @emoacht how can I set the `IsSelected` property? in template, none of elements have such property?

Comment: @emoacht Then, I don't know if you understood good : The problem is not to take back selected item value, but that I cannot click on them, as if `Over` was active on the main grid, not on sub elements. What I would like is to do as for a ListView, and select a list of days.

Comment: 1) I mean [ListBoxItem.IsSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected) property. Usually, if you click an item in ListBox, that item's IsSelected property will be turned to true. 2) It is simply because you have not defined visual interaction when the item's IsSelected property is changed. Thus you cannot see the change regardless of the current value of IsSelected property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mix up the visual effect when ListBoxItem's IsSelected property is true and actual value of that property. When an item container (ListBoxItem) or an item (content of ListBoxItem) in ListBox is clicked, that ListBoxItem's IsSelected property will be turned to true. By default, the change of this property will be reflected to the change of Background Brush of ListBoxItem. As such, a user notices the item is clicked.

But you effectively killed this visual effect by overriding the ListBoxItem's Style. To fix this, just add alternative visual effect to your Style.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="LBXI.DAY">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid>
                    ...
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            ...
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Opacity="1" FontSize="12" Margin="2,2,0,0" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                </Grid>
                <!-- Sample visual effect when IsSelected is true -->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: If I understand good, the selection was working, but I just didn't see it as I made "my own style"? Because I also tried to add `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>` (I added that attribute), but Binding was not working.

Comment: Now Binding is working fine. So I see 2 options : 1) I did something wrong with Binding last time. 2) This is your trick that helped. Anyway thanks for it, it helped a lot.